# How to Omit values for type definition from a set of values from Enum

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I defined two types from Enum picking up values

```
goodValue?: `${ValueOf<typeof SampleEnum>}`;
goodValueWithExclude?: `${ExcludeValue<typeof SampleEnum, 'ONE'>}`;

export enum SampleEnum {
  ONE = 'One_Value',
  TWO = 'Two_Value',
}
```

Type defintions:

```
export type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
export type ExcludeValue<T, K> = ValueOf<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>>;
```

But I dont want to invoke like this - `${ValueOf<typeof SampleEnum>}`. I want to invoke like `${ValueOf<SampleEnum>}`. Looks Simpler. I could not make it work. tried a lot of ways.

```
dummy1?: `${ValueOf2<SampleEnum>}`;
dummy2?: `${ValueOf2Exclude<SampleEnum>}`;

export type ValueOf2<T, K> = ValueOf<Pick<typeof T, Exclude<keyof typeof T, K>>>;
export type ValueOf2Exclude<T> = (T) => ValueOf<typeof T>;
```

None of them work - expecting like the below:

`AccountLessRequest.goodValue?: "Two_Value" | "One_Value" | undefined`
`AccountLessRequest.goodValueWithExclude?: "Two_Value" | undefined`

Comment: Sorry, but that won't work for reasons I lay out in the answer to the linked question.  You'll need to keep writing something like `ExcludeValue<typeof SampleEnum, "ONE">` and not something like `ExcludeValue<SampleEnum, "ONE">`.

Comment: can I use a function to get a type? and pass the enum ?